# search the files from multiple remote servers for specific file types

Tags: powershell, command

Could you help me for completing my small command , which i wrote for searching the files from remote servers around 150 servers across the regions

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content F:\Serverlist.txt) -ScriptBlock {dir c:\ -Recurse -File | where {$_.Extension -eq ".pst"} |select Length,LastAccessTime,Name,@{n='Path';e={$_.fullname}},@{n='Owner';e={$_.getaccesscontrol().owner}}} |Export-Csv F:\files.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here I'm searching for .PST files from multiple servers in C drive , I want to include other drive F also in the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, you can see this with `Get-Alias dir`.

If you would check the help with `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full` you'll see that `-Path` accepts multiple input:

```
-Path <String[]>
    Specifies a path to one or more locations.
```

So I think the solution would be to replace:

`dir c:\` with this `Get-ChildItem C:, F:`

Comment: I would also add that you should filter at the provider level where possible since that is much faster. I may not like the file system provider's filtering capabilities but filtering for extension is simple enough that it can handle it without issues. `dir c:\ -Recurse -File | where {$_.Extension -eq ".pst"}` becomes `GCI C:\,F:\ -Include *.PST`

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's faster. Thanks for the heads-up :)